# Angular, Modal is inserting duplicates

Tags: angular, firebase-realtime-database, bootstrap-modal

I'm just learning about Angular, and I'm doing a CRUD using Firebase.
My App uses an bootstrap modal for inserting data, It works good, but on inserting makes two insertions, I assume it's because the modal, but the modal must to be present for insert several records until all it's done. So is inserting the record twice or, insert the record and the next one as empty record if I clean the modal.

This is my service:

```
export class ArtistMusicService {
artitstCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Artist>; 
artists: Observable<Artist[]>;
artistDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Artist>; 

constructor( private _db: AngularFirestore ) {
console.log('Entrando al constructor del servicio artist-music.service');
this.artitstCollection = this._db.collection('artistas'); 


this.artists = this.artitstCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map( acciones => { 
  return acciones.map( a => {
    const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Artist;
    data.artist_id = a.payload.doc.id; 
    return data;
  });
}));
}


getArtistas() { // Get Data from db
console.log('Artistas => ', this.artists);
return this.artists;
}


// deleting
deleteArtist( artista: Artist ) {
this.artistDoc = this._db.doc( `artistas/${artista.artist_id}` ); 
this.artistDoc.delete(); // eliminar
}

// add (my little problem is here)
addArtist( artist: Artist ) {
this.artitstCollection.add( artist ); 
}

}
```

My component is:

```
addArtist( event, artist ) {
if ( this.artista.artist_name !== '' && this.artista.artist_origen !== '' && this.artista.artist_bio !== ''
&& this.artista.artist_generos !== '' ) {
  this._artistMusicService.addArtist( this.artista );  // agregamos con el servicio
}
this.artista = {} as Artist; // cleaning, If I clean, next record is emtpy, if not, next record is duplicate
}
```

And this is my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalArtistForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <form (ngSubmit)="addArtist()">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Artista</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body mx-3">
                <div class="md-form mb-5">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <label for="defaultForm-name">Artista</label>
                    <input type="text" id="defaultForm-name" class="form-control validate" name="artist_nombre" [(ngModel)]="artista.artist_nombre" />
                </div>

                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <label for="defaultForm-origen">Pais Origen</label>
                    <input type="text" id="defaultForm-origen" class="form-control validate" name="artist_origen" [(ngModel)]="artista.artist_origen" />
                </div>

                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="defaultForm-bio">Bio</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" id="defaultForm-bio" rows="5" name="artist_bio" [(ngModel)]="artista.artist_bio"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="md-form mb-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-lock prefix grey-text"></i>
                    <label for="defaultForm-genre">Genero</label>
                    <input type="text" id="defaultForm-genre" class="form-control validate" name="artist_generos" [(ngModel)]="artista.artist_generos" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="addArtist($event, artista)">
                    Agregar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>

<div class="text-center">
<a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-rounded mb-4" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#modalArtistForm" style="color:#ccffff;">Agregar Artista</a>
</div>
```

I hope, anyone can help me, 
thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [HTML5 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#the-button-element):

> The missing value default is the submit button state.

So in  your case, you button calls 'addArtist()' function, and as this is a submit event, as a result '(ngSubmit)="addArtist()"' added on 'form' tag also gets triggered.

I'd suggest to remove the 'addArtist()' from button.

Comment: You're right Siddhartha, I haven't seen it, but I removed the button from the form.  <form> , It works fine.
Thanks a lot ..!!